# Chrome extension and history.onVisited event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to the Chrome extensions development, and i have the following questions:
My extension should work in background, with no UI, and show an alert dialog every time the user visits a specific web page. So it should work always, in backround, when the browser is executed.

I was trying with the following code without results:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "history"
  ]
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(HistoryItem result) {
    if (result.url == "http://my.url.com") {
        alert("My message");
    }
}); 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. it returns `changeinfo.url`. by the way your problem can be solved by Bradley's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take HistoryItem out of the function and you are fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(result) {
    if (result.url == "http://my.url.com/") {
        alert("My message");
    }
}); 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Also note that I added the slash at the end of "http://my.url.com/" since that is what will be returned in result.url.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
<script>
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(function(e) { console.log(e)})
</script>
```

it's clearly